# How can I practice using nmap without scanning some real site or performing computer trespass?

Tags: nmap

I want to learn nmap and its various options. What can I do or setup in order to see examples of issues found by nmap - e.g., something with security holes on purpose.

Comment: U could `nmap localhost` first....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a specific URL for that : [scanme.nmap.org](http://scanme.nmap.org/)

> Hello, and welcome to Scanme.Nmap.Org, a service provided by the Nmap
>   Security Scanner Project and Insecure.Org.
>
> We set up this machine to help folks learn about Nmap and also to test
>   and make sure that their Nmap installation (or Internet connection) is
>   working properly. You are authorized to scan this machine with Nmap or
>   other port scanners. Try not to hammer on the server too hard. A few
>   scans in a day is fine, but dont scan 100 times a day or use this site
>   to test your ssh brute-force password cracking tool.
>
> Thanks
>   -Fyodor

If you are looking for vulnerable webapp here are some good lists :

- [Hacking Vulnerable Web Applications Without Going To Jail](http://blog.taddong.com/2011/10/hacking-vulnerable-web-applications.html)
- [Deliberately Insecure Web Applications For Learning Web App Security](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/deliberately-insecure-web-applications-for-learning-web-app-security)

Answer (score 2):

nmap won't disclose security holes, nmap will only disclose what services are running.

I'd highly recommend downloading virtualbox then getting an vunerable webserver like metasploitable to run on it. That way you can scan until your hearts content and also futher research what exploits etc are possible.

Comment: With Nmap scripting engine and scripts you can detect and exploit vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Metasploitable (**http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Metasploitable)**

It is a Virtual machine that has a whole bunch of vulnerable services installed. There is a tutorial that walk through how to exploit each service, part of this will be using NMAP to fingerprint the services.

Answer (score 1):

As a starter you should check the [scanme.nmap.org](http://scanme.nmap.org) provided by Nmap. Then download the [Metasploitable Virtual Machine](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/requirements/) provided by Offensive Security. With the Metasploitable VM you'll also practise your exploitation techniques. After these, i'd suggest you to sign up to several penetration testing online labs such us [Hack The Box](https://app.hackthebox.eu/home), [TryHackMe](https://tryhackme.com/) and [RootMe](https://www.root-me.org/?lang=en). When you are familiar with Nmap and other network scanning and packet capturing tools (Wireshark very useful), you could setup your own virtual or physical Lab for more Advanced - Field Testing.

***Virtual:*** Create a virtual lab provided by your VMs with a virtual network.

***Physical:***  Connect a computer to an existing router and configure router's settings according to what you want to do/practise. Then try the several scans.

Answer (score 0):

Go to hackthebox or any similar site you can practice as many scans as you want on retired machines. Just start the machine on your own and get it done.